# Why does my code not output the information from my SQL database correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to output the information from my sql database table onto my webpage.

This is the structure of my table.

```
Name      Type              Null    Default
Name      text              No      None
Picture   varchar(30)       No      None
Date      date              No      None
Price     int(11)           No      None
```

This is what I am using to query the database and to output the data:

```
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
$query="SELECT * FROM Events";
$result=mysql_query($query);

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {

$Name=mysql_result($result,$i,"Name");
$Picture=mysql_result($result,$i,"Picture");
$Date=mysql_result($result,$i,"Date");
$Price=mysql_result($result,$i,"Price");


echo "<b>$Name</b><br>$Picture</br><br$Date</br><br>$Price</br>";

$i++;
}

?>
```

This is what is being outputted onto the webpage:

```
$Name
$Picture

$Price
"; $i++; } ?>
```

Comment: Because you're closing the MySQL connection ___before___ looping over the resultset: if you had errors enabled, it would tell you this

Comment: it was very unclear if he was getting NOTHING printed, or if he was getting the variable names themselves printed. from his sample output it would seem to be the issue with html tag formatting, however that does not mean he wouldn't see the issue with a closed recordset after that was fixed

Comment: If your output contains PHP-code then it's (most likely) not parsed. Does your file have the PHP-open-tag (`<?php`)?

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 0):

there is error in typing the following line:

```
$num=mysql_numrows($result);
```

which is lacking "underscore" and should be:

```
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
```

This is the first mistake, The second is in this line :

```
echo "<b>$Name</b><br>$Picture</br><br$Date</br><br>$Price</br>";
```

look at `<br$Date,` you will find a missing > just before it , and should be

```
 <br>$Date
```

final note:  you should stop using mysql function and start using mysqli or PDO as suggested by PHP.net because the mysql extension is old and no improvement on it is being done.If you don't want to learn new things, consider using mysqli which can be very similar to using mysql ( in syntax ) but with more improvements.

Answer (score 0):

here is what needs to be done.....

1.forget `mysql` - its prone to injection and ancient history - use `mysqli_` or `PDO`

2.use proper chain to fetch data..

3.on completion, `close` connection

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$database);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM Events";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch object array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $Name=$row["Name"];
        $Picture=$row["Picture"];
        $Date=$row["Date"];
        $Price=$row["Price"];

        echo "<b>$Name</b>
              <br>$Picture<br>
              <br>$Date</br>
              <br>$Price</br>";
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Reference : http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: Im getting this error now, http://i.gyazo.com/8d5ef12e1b6986f5bec8c21824b57bce.png

Comment: @gibby97 : this is not error...check if there is `<?php` opening tag or not...from what i see, this is just PHP script rendered directly by browser, this happens only when PHP opening tags are missing!

Answer (score -1):

You can edit you code like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $Name = $row["Name"];
  $Picture = $row["Picture"];
  $Date = $row["Date"];
  $Price = $row["Price"];


  echo "<b>$Name</b><br>$Picture</br><br>$Date</br><br>$Price</br>";
}
```

Comment: nope...its would still print what ever is there in variables *if* there is any value in `$`...issue is with closing connection before the output!!! :)

Comment: This did not work, I moved the SQL connection to close after the loop but it is still not working

Comment: -1  read the manual. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php `If a dollar sign ($) is encountered, the parser will greedily take as many tokens as possible to form a valid variable name. Enclose the variable name in curly braces to explicitly specify the end of the name`